# Ubuntu won't boot anymore

Tags: boot, gpu-driver

I installed some nvidia drivers (from .run command) for my Mac mini 3,1. But now my pc won't boot and I can't get into the console from boot anymore.
Specs:
Intel Duo core 2 (P7500)
2GB of ram
Nvidia 9400m
160gb hdd

Comment: Kubuntu 20.04.2, nvidia 9400m driver for Intel CPUs from official Nvidia website.

Comment: We always recommend not to install from Nvidia binaries. Nvidia drivers, properly packaged and tested, are available at the Ubuntu repository. Nvdia Geforce 9400M is still supported by the 340 branch drivers. I believe this version is still available for 20.04 (it isn't for newer releases like 21.04).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Nvidia 450 graphics driver in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283357/installing-nvidia-450-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04)