# Ubuntu does not boot in graphical mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, windows-10

I recently installed ubuntu in 20.04 LTS. I have it with windows 10 in dual boot on a Dell precision PC.

My ubuntu does not boot in graphic mode: after I pass the grub, a black screen is displayed. The only way I found to go to graphic mode is to activate non-graphical mode with Ctrl+Alt+F2, and then re-switch to graphical mode with Ctrl+Alt+F1.
Otherwise ubuntu get stuck with a black screen and a flashing dash.

I have nvidiab and nouveau i915 drivers, and nouveau is the one used.

Why is ubuntu unable to boot automatically in graphical mode?

Comment: I have seen that before, can't remember exactly how I fixed it... but you have 3 different drivers trying to act on the machine, probably 2 different devices, and the hardware isn't winning... make a decision disable 2 of them and run one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that the driver nvidiafb is blacklisted: when I open the grub, there is the following line :"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nvidiafb.blacklist=1 quiet splash". I tried to replace nvidiabf by nouveau in this line, but it did not make any difference. Any idea to change the default driver?

Comment: Do a search on how to 'remove drivers from blacklist'. Also search blacklisting nvidiafb, or blacklisting nouveau, it may be easier to see how it is done and then you can reverse the process... (it's morning for me, have to run)... also edit your question with more additional info, and things you've tried.

Comment: Depending on the Nvidia graphics it has it may actually need proprietary drivers. Dell Precision says absolutely nothing because there are hundreds of different models spanning a couple of decades. Please consider [edit]ing and adding the actual hardware specifications, model number, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Nvidia graphics driver in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283357/installing-nvidia-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04)