# Fresh upgraded 22.04 freezes instantaneously after login

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, freeze, logging

I have a 2015 Acer S7 393, i5-5200U cpu, 8 Gb ram, HD5550 graphics, 2 * 64 Gb IRST kingston SSD, upgraded yesterday from 20.04.4 LTS (working fine) to 22.04 LTS.

The pc freezes after logging in (graphically, because using Ctrl+Alt+F2 on a virtual tty is ok, logging is ok, pc is working). It is with 5.15.0-48 kernel (and also with 5.4.125 old kernel, whereas 5.4.126 kernel crashes with kernel panic).

I cant 'find any hint in the logs to understand where it may come from : any hint ?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues after upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04.

In my case GNOME kept crashing and restarting after I logged in, apparently because of NVIDIA drivers getting messed up.

I fixed my graphics issues with the steps described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283357/installing-nvidia-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04)

In your case hopefully the `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` is smart enough to install the ATI drivers you need.

Comment: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've been too quick, did not search enough : found an hint [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/vkkyt1/ubuntu_2204_freezing_problem/) about gnome extensions, and remembered I saw a line 'writing' about that in syslog, so I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029376/how-do-i-enable-and-disable-gnome-extensions-from-the-command-line) ... 'et voila', I passed the freeze at loggin :-D

Can search and fix it definitively now.