# Clean install of 22.04.2 freezes after login

Tags: 22.04, login, crash

I have had quite a day with Ubuntu issues.

At 5 pm today I installed an update to 22.04.3. Upon restart I logged back in and was greeted with a black screen. I tried:

(1) Logging in with ctrl + alt + f5 and reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` via [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439249/ubuntu-22-04-boots-to-a-black-screen-with-login)

(2) Everything described [here](https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/) which includes

(a) trying to login with a freshly created user

(b) Deleting nvidia drivers

(c) Reinstalling GNOME Display Manager

(3) Someone said removing `.config/dconf/user` fixed it for them [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230945/black-screen-after-logging-in-after-upgrading-to-20-04)

None of these solutions worked so I said, whatever, we'll try a clean install

My clean install of 22.04.2, when I log in, I get to a grey screen with a frozen mouse

I'm on a MSI Prestige 15. Not sure what to do about this. Maybe upgrade to 23.04?

edit: I chose  the "Erase disk first" option on a 2nd reinstall, which enabled me to get to the desktop. I installed a bunch of common software and thought I was good to go. But no. After shutting down and coming back 2 hrs later, Ubuntu went to the frozen grey screen again after login.

I didnt even change much.

edit2: Now on August 19th after surviving a solid week on Ubuntu, I get the issue again after shutting down my machine and starting it again. I did not even update the software this time, I just installed straight off the 22.04.2 installer

I will have to go back to Windows because this is so bad

Comment: I have been dealing with something similar; one suggestion I came across was to use the 6.0 kernel instead of the 6.2 that is shipped with 22.04.3. I am still trying this fix, and will take a couple of days to confirm if the freezing behavior has stopped.

Comment: I'm using a fresh install OK but I haven't updated from the default 22.04.3 yet. I suspect that updating will make the issue return

Comment: Update: unfortunately, the freezing behavior continues, the 6.0 kernel doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: Same issue here on HP zbook :/ y u do dis Ubuntu :(

Comment: the `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinsall` worked for me - full answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/1453254/535677

Comment: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` gave me `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment` which lead to an answer that said to "work around the autoinstaller" by doing `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-530-open` which appears to have worked for me. I got it to go to the desktop once. We'll see if it lasts.