# Ubuntu 22.04 black screen no tty

Tags: command-line, upgrade, xorg, 22.04, tty

After upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04, my system became significantly sluggish which made me decide to use the xorg env instead of wayland. This didn’t work by just choosing xorg in the login screen, so I edited `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.

I uncommented this line:

`WaylandEnable=false`

Then I ran `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`

My laptop hanged for quite awhile. The screen was just black so I rebooted my laptop. I keep only getting the Ubuntu logo and the spinning wheel. After a while it disappears and I’m left with a black screen. I tried all sort of keys to get a tty or terminal none worked.  For example, alt+ctrl+f1~f9 ctrl+alt+f1~f9

Is there anything I can do to fix this situation without reinstalling? I don’t want to lose my stuff in /home and /download.

UPDATE

I was able to see this screen after pressing Alt+T, during the process when the wheel is still spinning and the u ubuntu logo on the screen (before it goes to black screen), and here’s what shows up, i tried to write anything like “sudo restart gdm3” but it took me to the black screen immediately.

[image]

and nothing happens, i guess my question is, is there anyway for me to get the tty or terminal during this whole thing other than Ctrl+alt+f1~7 or ctrl+T or ctrl+alt+T ?

Comment: my gdm3 stopped working out of blue after being usable for a while on 22.04 . switching lightdm seems to work but I really want my gdm3 back :(

Answer (score 1):

I am having similar issues after upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04.

In my case the TTY shows a black screen **but** it still functions.

I waited for the system to boot, pressed CTRL+ALT+F3, (saw a black screen)

Typed my user name (pretending to see the TTY Login) ENTER

Typed my password ENTER, typed my password again ENTER (because sometimes I mistype it)

Then I typed `sudo reboot` and my password again (for sudo)

The system restarted.

In theory I can use the TTY in this manner to fix my graphics driver issues. perhaps like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162535/why-does-switching-to-the-tty-give-me-a-blank-screen), but I haven't gotten that far yet.

update: I fixed my graphics issues with the steps described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283357/installing-nvidia-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04)