# Login Loop Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: login, 22.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, My User interface keeps on asking me to log in again and again.  I can log in by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.  I did updates Upgrades etc.

I can't find `.Xauthority` file, and gnome-session doesn't return anything,  I gave all permissions to the `/tmp` directory, and reinstalled `ubuntu-desktop`. I am using SVGA driver, and tried to search NVIDIA drivers and can't find any.  I am not sure how to automatically find a video driver and install it.  Any help on it is really helpful.

Comment: Your X server must be crashing as soon as you login. You probably need to install/reinstall/uninstall your nvidia drivers. Check with `lsmod | grep nvidia` and `lsmod | grep nouveau` which driver you're actually running. If you have nouveau but still proprietary GL lib installation, X will crash. Also make sure your GPU is still supported in 22.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: You have checked you have sufficient space in $HOME (your user directory), as if insufficient space is available, a GUI login will fail & login loop occurs. Text terminal logins will still occur allowing you to check & correct any disk space issues (*one cause only!*).  Your searching for X files may mean nothing as Wayland maybe used with 22.04; but you gave no specifics as to what hardware you're using, what actual 22.04 LTS install you're using (Desktop? Server?) etc.  You mention NVIDIA, does your machine have/use nvidia?

Comment: @guiverc: Pretty hard to find an answer that does not use lightdm on the above link. There are 59 answers for the OP to waste his time trying.

Comment: i use this link,  https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish .  i am getting debian GUI, not able to change to Gnome or Ubuntu,  still logs in as Debian.

Comment: ncdu is showing total disk usage 112.5 mib apparent size 111.6 mib items 2801.

df-h is showing plenty of space.  max I am seeing is 18% used.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issues after upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04.

In my case GNOME kept crashing and restarting *after* I logged in, apparently because of NVIDIA drivers getting messed up.

I fixed my graphics issues with the steps described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283357/installing-nvidia-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Specifically:

```
sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1278383)

Comment: This worked for me! Nothing else was working. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Try running these in the terminal:

````
$ sudo grub-update-gfxpayload && sudo grub-mkconfig && sudo update-grub && sudo update-grub2
$ sudo systemctl reboot -i```
````

Comment: You will want to:   cd /sbin   before hand.

Comment: first command gives me Command not found.

Comment: `$ ls -l $(which update-grub2)`

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  11 nov 26  16:13    /usr/sbin/update-grub2  -> update-grub2

and gfxpayload is not found in there either.. command not found.