# Loop Login Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, login, 22.04, password

Today, when I went to log into my pc, I just couldn't. The system returned to the user select page even with the password entered correctly. I found it strange that when entering the shell with the command `alt + ctrl + F3`, when I logged in as my user, I was logged out in a few seconds. I was only able to type commands when, after typing my username and password, I typed `ctrl + C` very quickly.
I tested a lot, reinstalled desktop-ubuntu, installed lubuntu, set permission on Xauthority file, removed old settings files, reset unity, set permission on /tmp folder, reset my problem user password and none of them worked. The temporary solution I found was to create a new user, but the old user is still there, and I can't access it. And in the .sessions-error files nothing appears. Does anyone know what it could be and how I can access my user with this problem?

Comment: a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442688/login-loop-ubuntu-22-04) may be worth looking at

Comment: @24601 Nothing changed, the error still persist

Comment: Have you added anything to one of your shell startup files that might be going into an infinite loop (such as sourcing .bashrc from itself)?

Comment: Review /var/crash for .crash files corresponding to each occurrence.