# Login loop on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Xwayland and gnome-shell blocked

Tags: nvidia, gnome, login, xorg, logging

My Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS got stuck in login loop. I did nothing special to cause it (maybe some general Ubuntu updates). I tried suggestions from https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/ but nothing helped. Only hint I have now is a log which appeared while I logged into my account through tty without GUI. It informs that Xwayland and gnome-shell tasks are blocked (log below). I tried to switch to `Ubuntu on Xorg` but nothing changes.

Actual symptoms:

1. Stuck in login loop
2. Log info appeared in console:

```
    [ 363.971410 ] INFO: task Xwayland:2280 blocked for more than 241 seconds.
    [ 363.971454 ] Tainded: G       W  OE        6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu
    [ 363.971480 ] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables the message.
    [ 363.974889 ] INFO: task gnome-shell:2738 blocked for more than 241 seconds.
    [ 363.974919 ] Tainded: G       W  OE        6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu
    [ 363.974946 ] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables the message.
```

3. Switching between `Ubuntu` and `Ubuntu on Xorg` changes nothing
4. CPU is heavily loaded, `top` utility shows `load_average: 1.00`

Runs on Lenovo ThinkPad P14s Gen 21

Graphics:

1. Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (VGA compatible controller)
2. NVIDIA TU117GLM [Quadro T500 Mobile] (3D contoller)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login Loop Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442688/login-loop-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: `edison23` answer from second link is the closest one to my actual solution, so I recommend to read if someone has problem similar to my. (My solution is described below as an answer to this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem and I am able to log in normally.

**Solution** was to remove nvidia driver and install specific one, as described below:

1. Remove nvidia driver as described [here](https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/). Judging from `journalctl` logs there were problem with `nouveau` (open-source nvidia driver).

```
sudo apt purge ~nnvidia
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
```

2. Install new driver ([help about Nvidia Driver Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaDriversInstallation)).
   The hack here was to install specific one (`525`), due to `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` which relies on automatic driver detection did not work.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:525
sudo systemctl reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, wasn’t able to use ubuntu-desktop but switching to KDE worked if nothing else works.

install KDE-full using:

```
sudo apt install kde-full
```

then use sddm instead of gdm.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem today. Although the Moose2109 solution works, it is not really fixing the problem. The solution is to install the proper nvidea drivers.
I installed KDE and then from the GUI I installed the proper nvidea drivers after finding the real issue. However, you can try to run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` or `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` and then reboot.