# Ubuntu 22.04 stuck in login loop on GUI login

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, login, desktop-environments, authentication

I am experiencing a persistent login loop issue on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine. Every time I attempt to log in, the screen blacks out briefly and then returns to the login screen.

Before the issue happened, I tried changing the keyring's login password to the same as before. I did this because it kept asking me for the keyring password when opening the browser or a few other programs. (It was a recommended fix I read somewhere else). But I don't think this is the issue after much troubleshooting.

Note: I have encrypted SSD and fingerprint reader.

I can still access the terminal through `Ctrl + Alt + F3`. Here is the list of things I have tried to fix it

- Check disk space: I have plenty of disk space on all partitions
- Reconfigure display manager: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`
- Reinstall display manager: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm3`
- Reinstall Ubuntu desktop: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
- Creating a new user and logging in with that: `sudo adduser test`
- Removed and reinstalled Nvidia drivers (recommended, 525, 530, 535):

```bash
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*         # removed old drivers before installing new ones

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall    # installing recommended drivers and restart
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525 # Installed and tried 525, 530 and 535
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-530
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535
```

- Checking for corrupted files (none showed up):

```bash
sudo apt-get install debsums
sudo debsums -c
```

- Switching to `Ubuntu on Wayland` on the login screen
- Tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442688/login-loop-ubuntu-22-04)

---

I wasn't able to paste the relevant `/var/log/syslog` because of size, so here is a link to it https://pastebin.com/abczYTbN

The status of `gdm3`

```bash
$ sudo service gdm3 status
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-09-29 12:55:33 CEST; 1h 42min ago
    Process: 1382 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1417 (gdm3)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18675)
     Memory: 6.5M
        CPU: 143ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
             └─1417 /usr/sbin/gdm3

Sep 29 12:55:33 user systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
Sep 29 12:55:33 user systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Sep 29 12:55:34 user gdm-launch-environment][1529]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=128) by (uid=0)
Sep 29 13:19:50 user gdm-fingerprint][9032]: gkr-pam: no password is available for user
Sep 29 13:19:50 user gdm-fingerprint][9032]: pam_unix(gdm-fingerprint:session): session opened for user user(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Sep 29 13:19:50 user gdm-fingerprint][9032]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly
Sep 29 13:19:52 user gdm3[1417]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Sep 29 13:19:52 user gdm3[1417]: Gdm: Child process 9032 was already dead.
Sep 29 13:19:52 user gdm3[1417]: Gdm: Unable to kill session worker process
```